# Скрипт для загрузки веб-страницы

Tags: javascript

Подскажите где найти код для загрузки веб-страницы *.php с другой страницы (или поместив javascript код в настройках браузера) через временные промежутки? Может есть браузеры где есть такие функции? у меня опера
спасибо

Comment: А почему бы не поступить как программист и попытаться сделать самостоятельно? В чём у вас проблема? В запуске функции по таймеру? В загрузке?

Comment: Ещё один копипастер. Наличие интернета приводит к тому, что многие слабые духод поддаются соблазку копировать куски кода из интернета и слеплять из вместе с целью достижения результата наименьшими усилиями. Чем-то похоже на то, как студенты-двоешники живут..

Comment: Где? В интернете. javascript.ru почитайте.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то вот код:
**HTML code:**

```
<div id="eaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">
    <div class="loadup">Загрузка...</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
<script> 
function show_online(){$.ajax({url: "site.ru", cache: false, success:function(html) { $("#eaaaaaaaaaaaaaa").html(html); }});}$(document).each(function(){show_online(); setInterval(show_online, 200000);});
</script>
```

Не забудьте подключить jQuery.
Краткая инструкция: site.ru - заменить на свое, 200000 - интервал обновление в мс 200000 мл = 200 с = 3 минуты 20 секунд

Comment: есть же шорткат `.load()` и надо упомянуть про cross-origin

Answer (score 0):

Если используете jQuery, то [вот](http://api.jquery.com/load/) простой способ получить страницу или ее часть:

```
$('#hello').load('/page.html #helloworld');
```

это вставит в элемент с id 'hello' элемент с id helloworld, который находится в page.html,

имейте ввиду, что получить страницу с другого домена таким образом невозможно, без [настройки на удаленной стороне cross-origin resource sharing](http://enable-cors.org/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/BVdL6/)